# Magento Mobile App - How to create it?

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile, app

I am writing to ask you an opinion on how to create an app for my website in magento . Where could I go to create it ? I read that Magento to already have the ability to create your own custom app . Where can I find a good tutorial for this?

Thank you so much for any help and straight

Comment: You can use various magento mobile app builder like http://mobikul.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can build a mobile app for your store either by hiring a professional developer or an app builder. If you are too specific on your requirement then I would suggest you to for professional developer but it would take lot of time and if you are looking for an instant solution then developing it with an app builder would not be a bad idea. You would find more details on building an magento app over here :

[Best way to build a Magento App for Magento site](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-choose-the-best-way-for-building-a-mobile-app-for-my-Magento-site)

[How to Create a Magento App for Android and Iphone](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-my-own-Magento-mobile-application-for-Android-and-iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create **api username & api key** for this.

go to backend, than `System > Web services >  Soap-xml RPC users & Soap-xml RPC` users , assign user to role.

Than you will get **session id** in app.

than for each feature you will get lot of APIS [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html). for some you may need to write your own API's